# REST API - nested objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I'm about to design my rest API. I wonder how can I handle objects such as one below:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
@ManyToMany
private Set<Bar> barSet;
@OneToMany
private Set<Zzz> zzzSet;
}
```

As you see object I want to expose to my rest API consists of other entity collections. I'm using Spring 4 and Jackson. Is it possible to return objects like one above - or do I have to create classes with primitive values only?

Comment: You can easily return objects like foo, but then you need to ignore the reference to foo in you bar class, otherwise jackson will crash.

Comment: Great. Could you tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Use the @JsonIgnore annotation and annotate the reference of foo in the bar class. This will prevent you from getting a circular dependencie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but you have to handle 2 problems :

1) at serialization, Jackson will call the getter `Foo.getBarSet()`. This will crash because by default, Hibernate returns lazy collections for `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` relationships.

If you don't need them, annotate them with `@JsonIgnore` :

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToMany
  private Set<Bar> barSet;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany
  private Set<Zzz> zzzSet;
}
```

If you need them, you must tell hibernate to load them. For example, you can annotate `@ManyToMany` and `@OneToMany` with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` (It is not the only solution btw) :

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Bar> barSet;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Zzz> zzzSet;
}
```

2) It can also cause some infinite loops :

- Serialization of Foo calls `Foo.getBarSet()`
- Serialization of Bar calls `Bar.getFoo()`
- Serialization of Foo calls `Foo.getBarSet()`
- [...]

This can be handled with `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` :

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToMany
  private Set<Zzz> zzzSet;
```

And on the other side :

```
@Entity
public class Zzz {

  @JsonBackReference
  private Foo parent;
}
```